# Error message: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'string[]'

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I am creating a dynamic array, and getting an error:

***Error message: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'string[]'***

The code is:

```
arrTeamMembers += tb.Text;
```

tb.Text contains values such as "Michael | Steve | Thomas | Jeff | Susan | Helen |"

I am trying to pass the values from tb.Text to arrTeamMembers. I am NOT trying to split the text.
How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "pass the values from tb.Text to arrTeamMembers"?  Does `arrTeamMembers` already have items in it?

Comment: no, arrTeamMembers is empty / null

Comment: Are you wanting to set `arrTeamMembers` to the individual values in `tb.Text`?  E.g. `[Michael, Steve, Thomas, ...]`

Comment: No, I want arrTeamMembers to contain "Michael | Steve | Thomas | Jeff | Susan | Helen |"

Comment: If you want the first item to be the value of `tb.Text` then you need to set it as jdmx and David Menton suggested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't just add strings to an array of strings.

Depending on what you are actually trying to do, you might want this:

```
string[] arrTeamMembers = new string[] { tb.Text };
```

or

```
arrTeamMembers[0] = tb.Text;
```

You probably want to use a List instead.

```
List<string> stringlist = new List<string>();
stringlist.Add(tb.Text);
```

Comment: string[] arrTeamMembers = new string[] { tb.Text };  

worked !!

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
arrTeamMembers = tb.Text.Split('|');
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is, arrTeamMembers is an array of strings, while tb.Text is simply a string.  You need to assign tb.Text to an index in the array.  To do this, use the *indexer* property, which looks like a number in square brackets immediately following the name of the array variable.  The number in the brackets is the 0-based index in the array where you want to set the value.

```
arrTeamMembers[0] += tb.Text;
```

Comment: Did you mean the `+=` to be an `=`?

Comment: No, I was using the same operator the OP used.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to split the text in the textbox then

```
arrTeamMembers = tb.Text.Split( '|' );
```

If this does not work, are you trying to append the textbox to the end of the array?

```
if ( arrTeamMembers == null )
  arrTeamMembers  = new string[0];

string[] temp = new string[arrTeamMembers.Length + 1];
Array.Copy( temp , 0, arrTeamMembers, 0, arrTeamMembers.Length );
temp[temp.Length - 1] = tb.Text;
arrTeamMembers = temp;
```

Comment: I am trying to pass the values from tb.Text to arrTeamMembers. I am not trying to split the text.

Comment: so you want?
string [] arrTeamMembers = new string[1];
arrTeamMembers[0] = tb.Text;

Comment: or you want something like this: 

string [] arrTeamMembers = {tb.Text}; 

which is the same as jdmx's (i.e. create an array of one element).