# How to split the string in mvc view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@foreach (var item in User)


string title = item.FirstName;
string lat = item.Lat.Split('/').ToString();
string lng = lat;
string description = item.description;
```

but it is showing Error like System.ToString()

Comment: Maybe adding some `{` and `}` around the `foreach` can help?

Comment: Hi { and } is there

Comment: Posting correct code with exact error message can get you quick answer.

Comment: Ok but how to split the string in Lat i am getting two string i need to split and assign to lng string please any one can help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the guides on how to ask a good question, they can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @foreach (var item in User)
{
    string title = item.FirstName;
    string lat = item.Lat;
    string lng = item.Lon;
    string description = item.FirstName;
 <div class="content-wrapper" style="padding-top: 1%">
   <script>
       var markers = [
            {

                title: '@title',
                lat[0]: '@lat.Split(',').ToString()',
                lng: '@lat[1]'
                //description:"title"


            }
       ];
       }
</script>

Comment: about code is not splitting can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var item in User)
{

string title = item.FirstName;
string lat = item.Lat.Split('/').ToString();
string lng = lat;
string description = item.description;

}
```

why do u need this`.ToString();`

if this worked fine`string title = item.FirstName;`

may be its already coming string ..
Put the code in try catch{} and put debug and see what the exact error is

Comment: if i added the try and catch then also it is not working can any one provide sample of code, it is really  help full

Comment: string str = (Session["UserName"].ToString()).Split('/'); try using like this and Make sure u are using right one '/' or '\'  if u are using '\' use it like this string str = (Session["UserName"].ToString()).Split('\\');

Comment: model IEnumerable<WebApplication4.Models.OnlineDriver>
{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var User = ViewBag.Online;
   }

@foreach (var item in User)
{
 
    string title = item.FirstName;
    string lat = item.Lat.Split('/').ToString();
    string lng = lat;
      
    string description = item.FirstName;

Comment: try like this string lat = (item.Lat.ToString()).Split('/');

Comment: try and tell if it worked if error whats the exact error

Comment: just do it  like this  string lat = item.Lat.Split('/');

Comment: An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'

Comment: hey there listen which part of the lat u want the one before or the one afteR??

Comment: see that next post id did check it there

Comment: For Example Lat=" " ;

Comment: check the above post try if it works the problem is it cant direct split right there and even after split u need to decide which part of u want

Comment: and Lon=" " ; both are separate value

Comment: ill be back in hour

Answer (score 0):

```
    @foreach (var item in User)
    {

    string title = item.FirstName;
    string lat = item.Lat;
    string latt=lat.Split('/');//text is hey/hi
    string latte  = latt[0];// if u want the 1st part like "hey"/hi this will give hey
    string latti  = latt[1];// if u want the 2nd part like hey/"hi" this will give hi
    string lng = lat;
    string description = item.description;

    }
```

[checkHere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337928/error-message-cannot-convert-type-string-to-string?rq=1)[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405902/cannot-implicitly-convert-string-to-string-when-splitting)[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949300/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-string)[here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/638311/Cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-string)
check them and see if u can solve it

Comment: This line  string latt=lat.Split('/');  showing String can not Converted into string same error

Comment: listen carefully now what is the exact string that is item.Lat giving?

Comment: Lat="12.9178,77.6723" i need to split this string one is lat and another one is lng

Comment: then instead of split('/') use split(',')

Comment: and i have added few links to the answer go to them and check out if can

Comment: be back in an hour

Comment: found the solution yet?